# How can I override spring.data.mongodb.uri to use mongo TestContainer in Spring boot tests?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, testcontainers

I'm trying to implement a bunch of tests using the Mongo TestContainer.
I see that the test container is successfully starting a Mongod instance in docker because I can connect to it using any Mongo Client.

I'm using `DynamicPropertySource` to override the `spring.data.mongodb.uri` to one from the TestContainer.

```
@DynamicPropertySource
static void mongoDbProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {

    registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri",
            () -> MongoInitializer.MongoContainerSingleton.getInstance().getReplicaSetUrl("testdb"));
}
```

However, in the logs, I see a timeout because mongoTemplate is still trying to connect to localhost:27017 instead of the port number exposed by the test container.

When I inspect `context.getEnvironment()` I see that `spring.data.mongodb.uri` contains the correct uri to the test-container.

I also removed the property from application.properties and tried adding the following to my test.

```java
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration")
```

Nothing worked.

How can I force mongoTemplate to connect to the TestContainer while running tests, while still using the value from application.properties otherwise?

Comment: Do you manually configure the `MongoTemplate` or use the auto-configured from Spring Boot?

Comment: I'm extending AbstractMongoClientConfiguration, so I guess that's where mongoTemplate is coming from. I would expect that the ApplicationContextInitializer from the test package is run before the mongoTemplate is initiated? Or is that a too simplistic view on things?

Answer (score 2):

@rieckpil pointed me in the right direction ... Thank you.

I just had to force Spring to use the spring.data.mongodb.uri property by overriding mongoDbFactory() of AbstractMongoClientConfiguration.

```
    @Bean
    public MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDbFactory() {
        return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(
                new ConnectionString(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.uri")))
        );
    }
```

The property set by @DynamicPropertySource in my test then takes priority over the one from application.properties.

getDatebaseName() from AbstractMongoClientConfiguration needs to be implemented, but is ignored because I don't use it in my implementation of mongoDbFactory().

Comment: I'm glad my question could help you find the solution :)